# How to change ngrok's web interface port address (not 4040)?

Tags: localhost, port, ngrok

ngrok's awesome [web interface](https://ngrok.com/) is pointed to `http://127.0.0.1:4040` by default. I have other applications listening on that port, however, and need to change it so that ngrok listens on, say, `http://127.0.0.1:4045`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Create a `config.yml` wherever ngrok is looking for its [default config](https://ngrok.com/docs#config-location) on your platform. If the directory doesn't exist, make it (on windows this is done by entering `.ngrok2.` as the folder name).

> **OS X**  /Users/example/.ngrok2/ngrok.yml
>
> **Linux**     /home/example/.ngrok2/ngrok.yml
>
> **Windows**   C:\Users\example\.ngrok2\ngrok.yml

Then, in `config.yml` enter

```
web_addr: 4045
```

Since this file is in ngrok's default config directory running `ngrok http 1337` from the command line, for example, will now run ngrok listening to your server at port 1337 and serving its web interface on `http://127.0.0.1:4045`

Comment: I can't seems to find the   config.yml   file.  I used homebrew to install ngrok on my mac, and it put here:           Symlinking Binary 'ngrok' to '/usr/local/bin/ngrok'.

Comment: Is there not a command line option here as well?

Answer (score 4):

If you're not sure where the config file is located, you can run:

```
$ ngrok config check
```

It will print the path that the config file is being read, so if you're using Snap version, you'll get something located under `~/snap/xyz/.config/ngrok/ngrok.yml`.

Then you can add `web_addr: 4045` there.