# ngrok web interface is not working

Tags: ngrok

I have ngrok working just fine. The tunnel status displays the forwarding address for http and https along with the web interface address.  I had to change the default web interface port from 4040 to 4045 because it conflicted with Parse-Server's web interface.  When I go to http://localhost:4045, I get nothing.  Any ideas greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this question: [How to change ngrok's web interface port address (not 4040)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36018375/how-to-change-ngroks-web-interface-port-address-not-4040).

The answer may help you change the default interface port from `4040` to `4045`.

I hope I was helpfull.