# Azure Bot Framework Emulator + Ngrok - Error : Failed to spawn ngrok

Tags: azure, botframework, ngrok

I can't seem to make Azure Bot Framework Emulator work with Ngork.

Environment :

- Ubuntu 22.04
- Python3

Steps I followed :

- [Create a bot with the Bot Framework SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-create-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=python%2Cvs)

  - => bot works fine locally with the Emulator
- [Tutorial: Provision a bot in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/tutorial-provision-a-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=multitenant%2Cnewgroup)
- [Tutorial: Publish a basic bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/tutorial-publish-a-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=python)

  - => bot works fine in Azure with the Test Web Chat
- install and configure [Tunneling (ngrok)](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/wiki/Tunneling-%28ngrok%29)

  - => the status page of Ngrok (http://localhost:4040/status) says it is **Onine**
    [image]
  - => "Ngrok Status Viewer" says "Tunnel Status" is on **error** in the Emulator
    [image]
  - => I have error messages in the Emulator : `Failed to spawn ngrok. Please go to the Ngrok Status Viewer and download the log file for a more detailed view of the error.`

```json
{
  "error_code": 102,
  "status_code": 400,
  "msg": "invalid tunnel configuration",
  "details":
    {
      "err": "yaml: unmarshal errors:\n line 1: field region not found in type config.HTTPv2Tunnel\n line 1: field path not found in type config.HTTPv2Tunnel",
    },
}
```

[image]

---

Edit 1 : following @sairamtadepalli-mt 's suggestion

If I change Ngrok's port (`web_addr`) in the config, I get a new error :

```
Connecting to bot on https://XXX.azurewebsites.net/api/messages
ngrok reconnected.
ngrok listening on http://localhost:36599
ngrok traffic inspector:
Will bypass ngrok for local addresses
Failed to spawn ngrok. Please go to the Ngrok Status Viewer and download the log file for a more detailed view of the error.
Error: The bot is remote, but the service URL is localhost. Without tunneling software you will not receive replies.
Connecting to bots hosted remotely
Configure ngrok
```

---

Edit 2 : following @sairamtadepalli-mt 's suggestion

Here is what I see in the Status Viewer and console (still the same error as initially...)  :

[image]

Error in the Emulator "Ngrok Status Viewer" :
`Looks like the ngrok tunnel does not exist anymore. Try reconnecting to Ngrok or examine the logs for a detailed explanation of the error.`

[image]

Error in the console :

```
Failed to spawn ngrok Error: {"error_code":102,"status_code":400,"msg":"invalid tunnel configuration","details":{"err":"yaml: unmarshal errors:\n  line 1: field region not found in type config.HTTPv2Tunnel\n  line 1: field path not found in type config.HTTPv2Tunnel"}}

    at NgrokInstance.runTunnel (/tmp/.mount_BotFraqqaRh3/resources/app.asar/app/server/ngrok.js:257:17)
    at async NgrokInstance.connect (/tmp/.mount_BotFraqqaRh3/resources/app.asar/app/server/ngrok.js:120:24)
    at async /tmp/.mount_BotFraqqaRh3/resources/app.asar/app/server/ngrokService.js:165:15
```

---

Answer (score 11):

I had same problems like yours using Ngrok v3 in a W10 PC.
I have tried several things like configuring tunneling with yaml files with no luck.

Finally, I have used Ngrok version 2.3.40 from this link: [ngrok releases](https://dl.equinox.io/ngrok/ngrok/stable/archive)

And now everything is working ok. HTH

Answer (score 2):

For now, please just use ngrok version 2 and not 3 for bot emulator. I had mine working by installing version 2.3.40 as mentioned by @cdiazal.

No update yet for emulator to be compatible with ngrok 3.

Read the issue thread here: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/issues/2389

Answer (score 0):

The problem was reproduced and the required changes to solve the issue are two.

**Solution 1:**

**Findings**: The major finding from the problem screenshot is, **Tunneling** software of ngrok was not installed properly. In the installation was completed from your end, but the configuration need to be changed from **port** side.

**Solution:** Re-install the tunneling software again from the scratch

**Solution 2:**

**Findings:** When the Emulator failed to load and launch the required operations, it means, the Post which was trying to connect is already in use. When it is trying to connect to the new port, the issue will happen

Follow the below link to install and configure Ngrok on Linux machine

https://ngrok.com/download

Configure the port which is not in use. Check whether 4040 is being used by web server or not. If it is being used, then change the port to 4041 and restart the emulator and check the connection.

Comment: Thanks @sairamtadepalli-mt !
I just purged and re-installed Ngrok via `apt` (`curl -s https://ngrok-agent.s3.amazonaws.com/ngrok.asc | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ngrok.asc >/dev/null && echo "deb https://ngrok-agent.s3.amazonaws.com buster main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ngrok.list && sudo apt update && sudo apt install ngrok`) and still have the same issue, even after a computer restart.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by and how can I "Configure the port which is not in use." ?

Comment: I also tried purging and re-installing with `snap` (`snap install ngrok`). Same issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36018375/how-to-change-ngroks-web-interface-port-address-not-4040

Check this link to change the port number

Comment: OK I changed the port, but I still have an error : cf. edited question

`Failed to spawn ngrok. Please go to the Ngrok Status Viewer and download the log file for a more detailed view of the error.`

Comment: Can you please share the screenshot of the log file from detailed view?

Comment: Which "detailed view" exactly ? (Sorry if this is a dumb question...)

Comment: Go to "Status Viewer" and download the log file. Please share the error mentioned in that log file for better understanding of the cause for this issue

Comment: cf. new content in the issue description. I can't see where/how to "download the log file" (no button or link...). Error message displayed in `stdout` : `Failed to spawn ngrok Error: {"error_code":102,"status_code":400,"msg":"invalid tunnel configuration","details":{"err":"yaml: unmarshal errors:\n  line 1: field region not found in type config.HTTPv2Tunnel\n  line 1: field path not found in type config.HTTPv2Tunnel"}}`